# How to make a reference of a game object that is being used to reference a non static var c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I am trying to make a way from which I can save a enum state and In order to do that I need make some reference of some non-static fields that I did using the 'new' keyword and unity gave me an error about that and I figured out I need to use `GameObject.GetComponent();` so I did that. The object I used is called Mybutton. I made a variable of it of Type LoadEveryThing that is a class in another script. I referenced that script as well because it's non-static like this `LoadEveryThing loadEveryThing = Mybutton.GetComponent<LoadEveryThing>();` then it presented a error because My button is non static. I can't make it static because it is important for it to be in the inspector. I tried this `LoadEveryThing MyButton =` I don't know what should I write after this and I even don't know will it work or not. So what should I do for it?

Full Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
 
public class SaveEverything : MonoBehaviour
{
    // What script to save
    public LoadEveryThing MyButton;
    const string key = "EnumValue";
 
    public void Save()
    {
        // What data to save
        string saveData = MyButton.state.ToString();
 
        // Where the data is stored
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "\\buttonstate.save";
         
        // Writes data to file
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, saveData/*, saveData1, saveData2, saveData3, 5*/);
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(path).Close();
            File.WriteAllText(path, saveData/*, saveData1, saveData2, saveData3, 5*/);
        }
    }  

    public static void LoadEnum()
    {
        { 
            LoadEveryThing loadEveryThing =  MyButton.AddComponent<LoadEveryThing>();
            string loadString = PlayerPrefs.GetString(key);
 
            System.Enum.TryParse(loadString, out ButtonState loadState);
            loadEveryThing.state = loadState;
            Debug.Log("l");
        }
    }
    
    public static void SaveEnum()
    {
        LoadEveryThing loadEveryThing =  MyButton.AddComponent<LoadEveryThing>();
        string saveString = loadEveryThing.state.ToString();
 
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(key, saveString);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log("s");
    }

    private void Save101()
    {
       LoadEnum();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
       
    }

}

public enum  ButtonState
{
    Buy,
    Equip
}
```

If anything is unclear let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your SaveEnum and LoadEnum methods are static, so they exist in the context of the entire class - SaveEverything. But the property MyButton is an instance property, so the static methods cannot access it. Either those methods need to also be instance methods or you need to find that button some other way.

It could for example be a parameter to the Save and Load. Or you could use the AssetDatabase.FindAssets to get the instance of the button.

Also you use AddComponent in your sample code, but talk about using GetComponent in your question. GetComponenet is fine, but AddComponent will add another instance of your script to your button or it will break, either case will not be the desired outcome

Comment: Thanks for replying but what do I need to do in my code I tried AssetDatabase.FindAssets like this ```AssetDatabase.FindAssets(MyButton);``` But it is giving additional errors. I also changed AddComponent to GetComponent. I need to find a way from which I can make a instance/reffer MyButton to the static methods. So what should I write in my code.